# Error trying to log in to facebook using php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to create simple php login for using facebook php-sdk. I am using example php code from facebook developers site:

```
 <?php
   // Remember to copy files from the SDK's src/ directory to a
   // directory in your application on the server, such as php-sdk/
   require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');

   $config = array('appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID','secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET', 'allowSignedRequest' => false // optional but should be set to false for non-canvas apps);
   $facebook = new Facebook($config);
   $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
?>
<html>
 <head></head>
<body>
<?php
if($user_id) {

  // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
  // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
  try {
    $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                                array(
                                  'link' => 'www.example.com',
                                  'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'
                             ));
    echo '<pre>Post ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';

    // Give the user a logout link 
    echo '<br /><a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">logout</a>';
  } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
    // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
    // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
    // just ask the user to login again here.
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
                   'scope' => 'publish_stream'
                   )); 
    echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
    error_log($e->getType());
    error_log($e->getMessage());
  }   
} else {

  // No user, so print a link for the user to login
  // To post to a user's wall, we need publish_stream permission
  // We'll use the current URL as the redirect_uri, so we don't
  // need to specify it here.
  $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'publish_stream' ) );
  echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

} 

?>      

  </body> 
 </html>
```

I have also tried several samples from internet and i always end up with same problem. After i grant permissions from Facebook, Facebook should return page to my page but instead it throws an error (this is translated error from my native language so it might be little bit different from actual English version): "ERROR This function is not available just now: Error processing this request. Try again later." And in URL there is "error_code=2&error_message=" if this helps anything? I have configured my app_id and app-secret in Facebook application page where also display name, email address, domain and site URL is set.

Also in that code i have set correct directory for SDK and app_id and secret_id.

Makes me wonder if i have faulty profile in Facebook apps? Every code i try gives same error. I have tried it with few different people. In users Facebook, applications section appears my application name and given permissions. Most likely this is some simple problem i just don't see, again...

Answer (score 0):

And problem was that my application was not public. Why it takes several hours to find problem and when asked in here you immedialy invent solution by our self? :D